# Кроссбраузерный keyCode

Tags: javascript

Использую такую инструкцию, но не работает в опере и хроме:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
   if (e.charCode == 108) {
      self.render();
   }
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кроссбраузерное решение.

Comment: Нажатие какой клавиши вам нужно перехватить?

Comment: L

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вообще не стоит использовать `e.charCode` для получения кода нажатой кнопки. Для этого в jquery было добавлено свойство `which`, которое нормализует передаваемые `charCode` и `keyCode`.

Почитать об этом можно [здесь](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

Пример кода:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e)
{
   // 13 == Enter
   if (e.which == 13)  {
       //Ваш код
   }
}
```

Comment: `-    if (e.which == 108) {`
`+    if (e.which == 76) {`

Comment: Не за что)) Примите ответ, чтобы не висел в неотвеченных =)

Comment: Ilya Pirogov: такого кода действительно нет) Просто скопировал из кода указанного в вопросе. Исправил

Comment: а как принять ответ?